# Components without VCL Forms in Delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi, vcl

This **may be** a question about something not need in the real world
. but i want to know can we do it (just for knowledge)

Can i show vcl components without VCL form . We can create and use non visual vcl but can we do it in visual vcl and make it visible on screen.

Or at least can we place a VCL in side a Form created using windows API,

Comment: Yes, this is probably possible, but maybe not very convenient.

Comment: This is a great comment because you said YES ! but HOW

Comment: Why do you ask how in the comment?  In the Q you say that you don't need to do it.  I expect it can be done.  Personally I'd host it in a TForm descendent and parent it with the ParentWnd property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, a VCL control (visual component) cannot exist outside of a VCL form.  However, you can place VCL control(s) in a VCL form, and then host the VCL form inside of some other kind of window.  Delphi's support for creating ActiveX controls does this - the VCL form (TCustomActiveForm, I think) provides the window handle that is handed out to ActiveX.  Your VCL components live inside that TCustomActiveForm or a descendent of that class and never know the difference.

You might be able to avoid the overhead of ActiveX if you're willing to do some digging and hoisting.  First, check out the ParentHwnd property or CreateParented method on TCustomForm.  That might be all you need - I can't recall off the top of my head, and it's been several years since I've seen the code.

If not, you can overridie the CreateParams method in a TCustomForm descendent and assign the non-VCL window handle to the Params.WndParent field.  Do this after calling the inherited CreateParams so that you get all the normal settings on everything else.  You will probably want to adjust the style and exstyle flags as well to remove the form's border, caption, etc.

Construct your VCL control in this custom form and size it to occupy the entire form area.

You might be able to do this with a lower level control than TCustomForm such as TCustomWinControl, but you may lose some keystroke / accelerator window message processing.  I know it can be done at the TCustomForm level.

Comment: @dthorpe Can't you just use ParentWindow or CreateParented?  EDIT: I now see that I'm questioning Danny Thorpe's knowledge of Delphi so I expect you are right!!

Comment: CreateParented might do it.  I thought we had implemented something to do this in a more automated fashion, but I don't have any VCL source handy and the online docs still leave a lot to be desired.

Comment: @dthorpe "online docs still leave a lot to be desired" 'nuff said!  CreateParented takes an HWND that winds up in Params.WndParent.  I'm not sure you need to do much with style flags, I think you could just set Form.Align := alClient.  I do this to put VCL forms inside other VCL forms.

You sure you don't fancy a return to Delphi product dev?!!  You and Barry would make a pretty formidable team!!!

Comment: @David: Working with Delphi code again would be a treat, but once you've left home you can never really return.

Comment: @dthorpe: You're right of course, but us users can but dream! If you'd stayed I'm sure we'd have 64 bit Delphi by now which is a particular bug bear of mine. It does at least sound as though good progress is being made in that area at last.

Comment: @David:  I left because Borland refused to invest any further in Delphi development.  They were actively dismantling and undercutting the product team every step of the way.  There would have been no 64 bit product work even if I had stayed.

Comment: @dthorpe: Interesting to hear. Rather sad really because it must have been a wrench for you to leave something you had poured your soul into. I never understood why Borland went after loss making ALM rather than money making Delphi. The only explanation that makes is that the execs got taken to nice golf courses by the ALM customers whereas us Delphi customers (the great unwashed) did nothing of the sort!

Comment: @David: This isn't really the right venue for this conversation.  Hit me up in email or twitter if you want.

Answer (score 5):

yes - if i understand your question well. I have done full installation program with no form, visual and non visual vcl, and api. Of course to make it visual (no console) you need a window.

Example code - no form (open the following .dpr file and compile):

```
program Window;

{
   This is an example of making an application
   without using the Forms unit. Forms.pas is the
   Delphi unit that makes your programs so damn
   huge! Forms.pas has all the code for translating
   the forms you create with Delphi w/components
   into windows. 
}


uses Windows, Messages;

{$R *.RES}

var
wClass:   TWndClass;  // class struct for main window
hFont,                // handle of font
hInst,                // handle of program (hinstance)
Handle,               // handle of main window
hEncrypt,             // handle of encrypt button
hDecrypt,             // handle of decrypt button
hEdit,                // handle of main edit
hLabel,               // handle of password label
hPW:      HWND;       // handle of password edit
Msg:      TMSG;       // message struct
dEncrypt,
dDecrypt: Pointer;    // default button procedures

(*------------------------------------------------*)

// This lines everything up
procedure Resize;
var
RCT:TRect;
begin
  GetWindowRect(Handle,RCT);
  MoveWindow(hPW,230,5,RCT.Right-RCT.Left-245,24,True);
  MoveWindow(hEdit,5,34,RCT.Right-RCT.Left-20,RCT.Bottom-RCT.Top-66,True);
end;

(*------------------------------------------------*)

// This is to cleanup and stop the program
procedure ShutDown;
begin
  DeleteObject(hFont);
  UnRegisterClass('Sample Class',hInst);
  ExitProcess(hInst); //end program
end;

(*------------------------------------------------*)

// Decrypts the text in hEdit with the text in hPW
procedure Decrypt;
var
x,i,                // count variables
sText,sPW: Integer; // size of Text, PW
Text,PW:   PChar;   // buffer for Text, PW
begin
  sText:=GetWindowTextLength(hEdit)+1;
  sPW:=GetWindowTextLength(hPW)+1;
  GetMem(Text,sText);
  GetMem(PW,sPW);
  GetWindowText(hEdit,Text,sText);
  GetWindowText(hPW,PW,sPW);
  x:=0; // initialize count
  for i:=0 to sText-2 do
  begin
    Text[i]:=Chr(Ord(Text[i])-Ord(PW[x]));
    Inc(x);
    if x=(sPW-1)then x:=0;
  end;
  SetWindowText(hEdit,Text);
  FreeMem(Text);
  FreeMem(PW);
end;

(*------------------------------------------------*)

// Encrypts the text in hEdit with the text in hPW
procedure Encrypt;
var
x,i,                // count variables
sText,sPW: Integer; // size of Text, PW
Text,PW:   PChar;   // buffer for Text, PW
begin
  sText:=GetWindowTextLength(hEdit)+1;
  sPW:=GetWindowTextLength(hPW)+1;
  GetMem(Text,sText);
  GetMem(PW,sPW);
  GetWindowText(hEdit,Text,sText);
  GetWindowText(hPW,PW,sPW);
  x:=0; // initialize count
  for i:=0 to sText-2 do
  begin
    Text[i]:=Chr(Ord(Text[i])+Ord(PW[x]));
    Inc(x);
    if x=(sPW-1)then x:=0;
  end;
  SetWindowText(hEdit,Text);
  FreeMem(Text);
  FreeMem(PW);
end;

(*------------------------------------------------*)

// This function processes every message sent to the Encrypt Button
function EncryptProc(hWnd,Msg,wParam,lParam:Longint):Longint; stdcall;
var
i: Integer;
begin
  // Always pass the message to the Default procedure
  Result:=CallWindowProc(dEncrypt,hWnd,Msg,wParam,lParam);

  case Msg of
  // If the user presses TAB we're gunna switch the
  // focus over to the Decrypt button.
  WM_KEYDOWN: if wParam=9 then SetFocus(hDecrypt);
  end;

end;

(*------------------------------------------------*)

// This function processes every message sent to the Decrypt Button
function DecryptProc(hWnd,Msg,wParam,lParam:Longint):Longint; stdcall;
begin
  // Always pass the message to the Default procedure
  Result:=CallWindowProc(dEncrypt,hWnd,Msg,wParam,lParam);

  case Msg of
  // if the user presses TAB we're gunna switch
  // the focus back to the Encrypt button.
  WM_KEYDOWN: if wParam=9 then SetFocus(hEncrypt);
  end;

end;

(*------------------------------------------------*)

// This function processes every message sent to our Main window
function WindowProc(hWnd,Msg,wParam,lParam:Longint):Longint; stdcall;
begin
  // Always pass the message to the Default procedure
  Result:=DefWindowProc(hWnd,Msg,wParam,lParam);

  case Msg of
  WM_SIZE:    Resize;
  // When buttons are clicked the message is passed to
  // the parent window, so we handle it here.
  WM_COMMAND: if      lParam=hEncrypt then Encrypt
              else if lParam=hDecrypt then Decrypt;
  WM_DESTROY: ShutDown;
  end;

end;

(*------------------------------------------------*)

// This is the main program function (WinMain)
begin

  hInst:=GetModuleHandle(nil); // get the application instance
                               // hInstance returns zilch

  with wClass do
  begin
    Style:=         CS_PARENTDC;
    hIcon:=         LoadIcon(hInst,'MAINICON');
    lpfnWndProc:=   @WindowProc;
    hInstance:=     hInst;
    hbrBackground:= COLOR_BTNFACE+1;
    lpszClassName:= 'Sample Class';
    hCursor:=       LoadCursor(0,IDC_ARROW);
  end;

  // Once our class is registered we
  // can start making windows with it
  RegisterClass(wClass);

  // Create our main window
  Handle:=CreateWindow(
    'Sample Class',          // Registered Class Name
    'Encrypter', // Title of Window
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW or   // Basic Window Style
    WS_VISIBLE,              // Make it Visible
    10,                      // Left
    10,                      // Top
    400,                     // Width
    300,                     // Height
    0,                       // Parent Window Handle
    0,                       // Handle of Menu
    hInst,                   // Application Instance
    nil);                    // Structure for Creation Data

  // Create the Encrypt button
  hEncrypt:=CreateWindow(
    'Button',
    'Encrypt',
    WS_VISIBLE or WS_CHILD or BS_PUSHLIKE or BS_TEXT,
    5,5,65,24,Handle,0,hInst,nil);

  // Create the Decrypt button
  hDecrypt:=CreateWindow(
    'Button',
    'Decrypt',
    WS_VISIBLE or WS_CHILD or BS_PUSHLIKE or BS_TEXT,
    75,5,65,24,Handle,0,hInst,nil);

  // Create the main Edit
  hEdit:=CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, // this EX style is for the beveled edge
    'Edit',
    '',
    WS_VISIBLE or WS_CHILD or ES_LEFT or ES_MULTILINE or ES_WANTRETURN or ES_AUTOVSCROLL or WS_VSCROLL,
    5,34,380,234,Handle,0,hInst,nil);

  // Create the password Edit
  hPW:=CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
    'Edit',
    '',
    WS_VISIBLE or WS_CHILD or ES_LEFT or ES_AUTOHSCROLL or ES_PASSWORD,
    230,5,155,24,Handle,0,hInst,nil);

  hLabel:=CreateWindow(
    'Static',
    'Password:',
    WS_VISIBLE or WS_CHILD or SS_LEFT,
    160,10,70,20,Handle,0,hInst,nil);

  // Create a custom font for our window otherwise
  // everything would use the system font (blech!)
  hFont:=CreateFont(
    -12,                           // Height
    0,                             // Width
    0,                             // Angle of Rotation
    0,                             // Orientation
    0,                             // Weight
    0,                             // Italic
    0,                             // Underline
    0,                             // Strike Out
    DEFAULT_CHARSET,               // Char Set
    OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,            // Precision
    CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,           // Clipping
    DEFAULT_QUALITY,               // Render Quality
    DEFAULT_PITCH or FF_DONTCARE,  // Pitch & Family
    'MS Sans Serif');              // Font Name

  // Set the fonts for all our controls
  SendMessage(hEncrypt,WM_SETFONT,hFont,0);
  SendMessage(hDecrypt,WM_SETFONT,hFont,0);
  SendMessage(hEdit,WM_SETFONT,hFont,0);
  SendMessage(hPW,WM_SETFONT,hFont,0);
  SendMessage(hLabel,WM_SETFONT,hFont,0);

  // Subclass Encrypt Button (assign it a custom WindowProc)
  dEncrypt:=Pointer(GetWindowLong(hEncrypt,GWL_WNDPROC));
  SetWindowLong(hEncrypt,GWL_WNDPROC,Longint(@EncryptProc));

  // Subclass Decrypt Button
  dDecrypt:=Pointer(GetWindowLong(hDecrypt,GWL_WNDPROC));
  SetWindowLong(hDecrypt,GWL_WNDPROC,Longint(@DecryptProc));

  // The reason I don't subclass the Edit controls here
  // is because they don't do anything custom. If I wanted
  // them to Beep or something whenever you typed a "G" then
  // I would subclass them.

  // Focus on first control (otherwise people with no mouse are screwed)
  SetFocus(hEncrypt);

  // Now we loop GetMessage to process each Message in
  // our main window's message list. Every time the main
  // window recieves a message its added to the list, so
  // this loop here will eventually process it.

  while(GetMessage(Msg,Handle,0,0))do
  begin
    TranslateMessage(Msg);             // Translate any keyboard Msg's
    DispatchMessage(Msg);              // Send it to our WindowProc
  end;                                 // for processing.

end.
```

Comment: You have misunderstood the OP. He has a custom control `TMyCustomControl` that he wishes to use.

Comment: But My question is can i show vcl on a win api form(Non vcl form)

Comment: Why not if you register all the vcl classes, parent classes etc. you need (may be wrapping some of them) within the window program. I guest using complex vcl classes will not be an easy task.

Comment: You've accepted an answer that doesn't answer your question!  Bizarre.  I don't see any VCL here at all.  It only uses Windows and Messages.  It's a classic Petzold style Windows program.

Comment: @ David Heffernan yes but i add some code to this answer in my own answer

Answer (score 3):

For VCL **components** answer is clearly yes. **Components** are usable out of form context w/o any hassle, just bypass ownership mechanism by specifying `nil` and destroy instance *manually* when finished.

```
NoLongerDependsOnForm := TSomeComponent.Create(nil);
NoLongerDependsOnForm.This;
NoLongerDependsOnForm.That;
FreeAndNil(NoLongerDependsOnForm);
```

With VCL **controls** things are waaay more complex because any *child* window needs parent window. Thus, reusing TWinControl within generic window is possible only theoretically (have to write VCL stub to make it work). So, answer is marginally no.

And i'm begging you, please stop mixing up terms *form* and *window*. (Further reading: top-level and child windows)

Comment: To be fair, Microsoft make it easy to get them mixed up given that the OS is called Windows and 99.99% of population would refer to a form as a window!

Answer (score 0):

A control may look for and access properties in the owner and parent container, accessing them as VCL classes. If they are not, there are good chance the VCL control won't work.

One way to avoid that is to wrap them as ActiveX controls. Then you can use then in whatever language that supports ActiveX controls.

Answer (score 0):

This is not just my own code but a mixer of all your code wich worked for me

Just add these code for **volvox** 's answer(*which i have accepted and on the top*)

```
uses
  Windows,
  Messages,buttons,stdctrls;


var
abtn:TButton ;


begin
//  after all declaration
 abtn := TButton.Create(nil) ;
 abtn.ParentWindow := hEdit ; // use window handle but i use hedit because my button     will be hidden by another button in example
end
```

Comment: Simpler is abtn := TButton.CreateParented(hEdit)